# creating a table view and restricting the access by hours

Tags: sql

I am  new in here and wonder if any one can give me some help/ideas with this.

I am creating a view as follow:

```
CREATE VIEW V_ORDERS
AS 
SELECT ORDERNUMBER, 
       CUSTOMERNUMBER, 
       DATEORDERPLACED, 
       DELIVERYINSTRUCTION, 
SCHEDULEID
FROM ORDERS
```

so i grant access to sumone as follow:

```
GRANT ALL ON V_ORDERS TO "SUMONESPACE"
```

but i want to restrict the access to the table to the working hours 9:00am till 6:00pm

thank you in advance

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2, ...)

Answer (score 6):

If nothing else helps, you can still deliver an empty table:

```
CREATE VIEW bla AS
SELECT blabla
WHERE HOUR(NOW()) BETWEEN 9 AND 18
```

Maybe you can add a `UNION`:

```
UNION
SELECT 'You','should','be','at','home','now!'
WHERE HOUR(NOW()) NOT BETWEEN 9 AND 18
```

Refinement of the first idea: you could create a 0-or-1 row view for joining (if Oracle happens to calculate the sysdate expression with each row which might be slower):

```
CREATE VIEW STAFF_ORDERVIEW_ALLOWED( current_sys_date ) AS 
SELECT sysdate
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) + 9/24 AND trunc(sysdate) + 18/24;
```

Then you just have to join

```
CREATE VIEW STAFF_ORDERVIEW_ATHOURS( current_sys_date, ordernumber, customernumber,
  dateorderplaced, deliveryinstruction, scheduleid) AS
SELECT sysdate, ORDERNUMBER, CUSTOMERNUMBER,
  DATEORDERPLACED, DELIVERYINSTRUCTION, SCHEDULEID
FROM STAFF_ORDERVIEW_ALLOWED
INNER JOIN ORDERS;
```

Comment: Nice! Although I think you want "BETWEEN" rather than "NOT BETWEEN" in the UNION query. Also, in Oracle one would use `TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24'))` rather than `HOUR(NOW())`.

Comment: Hi thank you for ur help and sorry for the late reply
I managed to work it out with some mates help

CREATE VIEW STAFF_ORDERVIEW_ATHOURS(
 current_sys_date, 
 ordernumber, 
 customernumber, 
 dateorderplaced,
 deliveryinstruction, 
 scheduleid) AS
SELECT 
 sysdate, 
 ORDERNUMBER, 
 CUSTOMERNUMBER, 
 DATEORDERPLACED, 
 DELIVERYINSTRUCTION, 
 SCHEDULEID
FROM ORDERS
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) + 9/24 
  AND trunc(sysdate) + 18/24;

and this is what we have come out with
i thought i would share the answer just in case someone else comes across this question

Comment: by the way this is by using oracle, am not sure if it differs using other databases such as PostgreSQL, etc

Comment: Hi, good to hear it worked. If you wish you can post your solution as an answer. I updated my answer with a version using inner join.